# Keras module.summary() result - negative dimension values in 'output shape'

Tags: python, keras

I'm running code for 'Alexnet' on Keras(Theano backend):

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])#, AUCEpoch,PrecisionEpoch,RecallEpoch,F1Epoch])
print(X_train.shape)
print(model.summary())

debug result:
(268, 3, 227, 227)
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 3, 227, 227)   0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_1 (Convolution2D)           (None, -1, 55, 96)    2636928     input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, -1, 27, 96)    0           conv_1[0][0]                     
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convpool_1 (Lambda)              (None, -1, 27, 96)    0           maxpooling2d_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
zeropadding2d_1 (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 3, 31, 96)     0           convpool_1[0][0]                 
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)                (None, 1, 31, 96)     0           zeropadding2d_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)                (None, 1, 31, 96)     0           zeropadding2d_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_2_1 (Convolution2D)         (None, -3, 27, 128)   307328      lambda_1[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_2_2 (Convolution2D)         (None, -3, 27, 128)   307328      lambda_2[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_2 (Merge)                   (None, -6, 27, 128)   0           conv_2_1[0][0]                   
                                                                   conv_2_2[0][0]                   
______________________________________________________________________________.......................
.......................
______________________________________________________________________________                      
mil_1 (Convolution2D)            (None, -5, 6, 128)    16512       convpool_5[0][0]                 
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
mil_2 (Convolution2D)            (None, -5, 6, 128)    16512       mil_1[0][0]                      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
mil_3 (Convolution2D)            (None, -5, 6, 2)      258         mil_2[0][0]                      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
softmax (Softmax4D)              (None, -5, 6, 2)      0           mil_3[0][0]                      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
output (MaxPooling2D)            (None, -1, 1, 2)      0           softmax[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)                (None, -2)            0           output[0][0]                     
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Recalcmil (Recalc)               (None, -2)            0           flatten[0][0]                    
====================================================================================================
Total params: 5,497,730
Trainable params: 5,497,730
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
None

ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected Recalcmil to have shape (None, -2) but got array with shape (268, 2)
```

I'm really confused by the output shape for the natwork. I don't understand What the matter is that leads to the negative number for the shape.

Here is the source code for the model:

```
np.random.seed(1)
#srng = RandomStreams(1)
fold = 2 # 4
valfold = 4
lr = 5e-5
nb_epoch = 500
batch_size = 80
l2factor = 1e-5
l1factor = 0#2e-7
weighted = False #True
noises = 50
#data_augmentation = True
data_augmentation = False

modelname = 'alexnet' # miccai16, alexnet, levynet, googlenet
#pretrain = True
pretrain = False

mil=True
savename = modelname+'_fd'+str(fold)+'_vf'+str(valfold)+'_lr'+str(lr)+'_l2'+str(l2factor)+'_l1'\
+str(l1factor)+'_ep'+str(nb_epoch)+'_bs'+str(batch_size)+'_w'+str(weighted)+'_dr'+str(False)+str(noises)+str(pretrain)+'_mil'+str(mil)
print(savename)
nb_classes = 2
# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 227, 227
# the CIFAR10 images are RGB
img_channels = 1
# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
trX, y_train, teX, y_test, teteX, y_test_test = inbreast.loaddataenhance(fold, 5, valfold=valfold)
trY = y_train.reshape((y_train.shape[0],1))
teY = y_test.reshape((y_test.shape[0],1))
teteY = y_test_test.reshape((y_test_test.shape[0],1))
print('tr, val, te pos num and shape')
print(trY.sum(), teY.sum(), teteY.sum(), trY.shape[0], teY.shape[0], teteY.shape[0])
ratio = trY.sum()*1./trY.shape[0]*1.
print('tr ratio'+str(ratio))
weights = np.array((ratio, 1-ratio))
# trYori = np.concatenate((1-trY, trY), axis=1)
# teY = np.concatenate((1-teY, teY), axis=1)
# teteY = np.concatenate((1-teteY, teteY), axis=1)

X_train = trX.reshape(-1, img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)
X_test = teX.reshape(-1, img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)
X_test_test = teteX.reshape(-1, img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)


# X_train = trX.reshape(-1, img_rows, img_cols, img_channels)
# X_test = teX.reshape(-1, img_rows, img_cols, img_channels
# X_test_test = teteX.reshape(-1, img_rows, img_cols, img_channels)


print('tr, val, te mean, std')
print(X_train.mean(), X_test.mean(), X_test_test.mean())
# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)
Y_test_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test_test, nb_classes)
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'val samples')
print(X_test_test.shape[0], 'test samples')
model = Sequential()
if modelname == 'alexnet':
  X_train_extend = np.zeros((X_train.shape[0],3, 227, 227))
  for i in xrange(X_train.shape[0]):
    rex = np.resize(X_train[i,:,:,:], (227, 227))
    X_train_extend[i,0,:,:] = rex
    X_train_extend[i,1,:,:] = rex
    X_train_extend[i,2,:,:] = rex
  X_train = X_train_extend
  X_test_extend = np.zeros((X_test.shape[0], 3,227, 227))
  for i in xrange(X_test.shape[0]):
    rex = np.resize(X_test[i,:,:,:], (227, 227))
    X_test_extend[i,0,:,:] = rex
    X_test_extend[i,1,:,:] = rex
    X_test_extend[i,2,:,:] = rex
  X_test = X_test_extend
  X_test_test_extend = np.zeros((X_test_test.shape[0], 3, 227, 227))
  for i in xrange(X_test_test.shape[0]):
    rex = np.resize(X_test_test[i,:,:,:], (227,227))
    X_test_test_extend[i,0,:,:] = rex
    X_test_test_extend[i,1,:,:] = rex
    X_test_test_extend[i,2,:,:] = rex
  X_test_test = X_test_test_extend
  if pretrain:  # 227*227
    alexmodel = convnet('alexnet', weights_path='alexnet_weights.h5', heatmap=False, l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor)
    model = convnet('alexnet', outdim=2, l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor, usemil=mil)
    for layer, mylayer in zip(alexmodel.layers, model.layers):
      print(layer.name)
      if mylayer.name == 'mil_1':
        break
      else:
        weightsval = layer.get_weights()
        print(len(weightsval))
        mylayer.set_weights(weightsval)
  else:
    model = convnet('alexnet', outdim=2, l1=l1factor,l2=l2factor, usemil=mil)

# let's train the model using SGD + momentum (how original).
sgd = Adam(lr=lr) #SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])#, AUCEpoch,PrecisionEpoch,RecallEpoch,F1Epoch])
print(X_train.shape)
print(model.summary())
#filepath = savename+'-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}-{val_acc:.2f}.hdf5' #-{val_auc:.2f}-\
#{val_prec:.2f}-{val_reca:.2f}-{val_f1:.2f}.hdf5'
#checkpoint0 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
#checkpoint1 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
checkpoint0 = LossEpoch(savename, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), interval=1)
checkpoint1 = ACCEpoch(savename, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), interval=1)
checkpoint2 = AUCEpoch(savename, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), interval=1)
checkpoint3 = PrecisionEpoch(savename, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), interval=1)
checkpoint4 = RecallEpoch(savename, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), interval=1)
checkpoint5 = F1Epoch(savename, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), interval=1)
#checkpoint2 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_auc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
#checkpoint3 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_prec', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
#checkpoint4 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_reca', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
#checkpoint5 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_f1', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint0, checkpoint1, checkpoint2, checkpoint3, checkpoint4, checkpoint5]
#callbacks_list = [AUCEpoch, PrecisionEpoch, RecallEpoch, F1Epoch, checkpoint0, checkpoint1]
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
#X_train /= 255
#X_test /= 255

if not data_augmentation:
  print('Not using data augmentation.')
  model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
              validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
              shuffle=True)
else:
  print('Using real-time data augmentation.')
  # this will do preprocessing and realtime data augmentation
  datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
        rotation_range=45.0,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False,
        zerosquare=True,
        zerosquareh=noises,
        zerosquarew=noises,
        zerosquareintern=0.0)  # randomly flip images
  # compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
  # (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
  datagen.fit(X_train)
  # fit the model on the batches generated by datagen.flow()

  if weighted:
    model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size),
                        samples_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0],
                        nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
                        validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
                        callbacks=callbacks_list,
                        class_weight=[weights[0], weights[1]])
  else:
    print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
    print('Y_train shape:', Y_train.shape)

    print('X_test shape:', X_test.shape)
    print('Y_test shape:', Y_test.shape)
    print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
    print(X_test.shape[0], 'val samples')
    print(X_test_test.shape[0], 'test samples')
    model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size),
                        samples_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0],
                        nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
                        validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
                        callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

I think I've the right input format as (None,3,227,227),but the output is wrong.

And here is the 'alexnet':

```
def AlexNet(outdim=1000, weights_path=None, heatmap=False, l1=0, l2=0, usemil=False, usemymil=False, k=1., usemysoftmil=False, softmink=1., softmaxk=1.,\
    sparsemil=False, sparsemill1=0., sparsemill2=0., saveact=False):
    l1factor = l1
    l2factor = l2
    if heatmap:
        inputs = Input(shape=(3,None,None))
    else:
        inputs = Input(shape=(3,227,227))

    conv_1 = Convolution2D(96, 11, 11,subsample=(4,4),activation='relu', W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor),
                           name='conv_1')(inputs)

    conv_2 = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2,2))(conv_1)
    conv_2 = crosschannelnormalization(name="convpool_1")(conv_2)
    conv_2 = ZeroPadding2D((2,2))(conv_2)
    conv_2 = merge([
        Convolution2D(128,5,5,activation="relu",name='conv_2_'+str(i+1), W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(
            splittensor(ratio_split=2,id_split=i)(conv_2)
        ) for i in range(2)], mode='concat',concat_axis=1,name="conv_2")

    conv_3 = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(conv_2)
    conv_3 = crosschannelnormalization()(conv_3)
    conv_3 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv_3)
    conv_3 = Convolution2D(384,3,3,activation='relu',name='conv_3', W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(conv_3)

    conv_4 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv_3)
    conv_4 = merge([
        Convolution2D(192,3,3,activation="relu",name='conv_4_'+str(i+1), W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(
            splittensor(ratio_split=2,id_split=i)(conv_4)
        ) for i in range(2)], mode='concat',concat_axis=1,name="conv_4")

    conv_5 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv_4)
    conv_5 = merge([
        Convolution2D(128,3,3,activation="relu",name='conv_5_'+str(i+1), W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(
            splittensor(ratio_split=2,id_split=i)(conv_5)
        ) for i in range(2)], mode='concat',concat_axis=1,name="conv_5")

    dense_1 = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2,2),name="convpool_5")(conv_5)

    if heatmap:
        dense_1 = Convolution2D(4096,6,6,activation="relu",name="dense_1",W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_1)
        dense_2 = Convolution2D(4096,1,1,activation="relu",name="dense_2",W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_1)
        dense_3 = Convolution2D(outdim, 1,1,name="dense_3",W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_2)
        prediction = Softmax4D(axis=1,name="softmax")(dense_3)
    elif usemil:
        dense_1 = Convolution2D(128,1,1,activation='relu',name='mil_1',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_1)
        dense_2 = Convolution2D(128,1,1,activation='relu',name='mil_2',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_1)
        dense_3 = Convolution2D(outdim,1,1,name='mil_3',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_2)
        prediction_1 = Softmax4D(axis=1, name='softmax')(dense_3)
        #prediction = Flatten(name='flatten')(prediction_1)
        #dense_3 = Dense(outdim,name='dense_3',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(prediction)
        #prediction = Activation("softmax",name="softmax2")(dense_3)

        prediction_1 = MaxPooling2D((6,6), name='output')(prediction_1)
        prediction = Flatten(name='flatten')(prediction_1)
        prediction = Recalc(axis=1, name='Recalcmil')(prediction)
    elif usemymil:
        dense_1 = Convolution2D(128,1,1,activation='relu',name='mil_1',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_1)
        dense_2 = Convolution2D(128,1,1,activation='relu',name='mil_2',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_1)
        dense_3 = Convolution2D(1,1,1,activation='sigmoid',name='mil_3',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_2)
        #prediction_1 = Softmax4D(axis=1, name='softmax')(dense_3)
        #prediction = ExtractDim(axis=1, name='extract')(prediction_1)
        prediction = Flatten(name='flatten')(dense_3)
        prediction = ReRank(k=k, label=1, name='output')(prediction)
    elif usemysoftmil:
        dense_1 = Convolution2D(128,1,1,activation='relu',name='mil_1',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_1)
        dense_2 = Convolution2D(128,1,1,activation='relu',name='mil_2',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_1)
        dense_3 = Convolution2D(1,1,1,activation='sigmoid',name='mil_3',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_2)
        #prediction_1 = Softmax4D(axis=1, name='softmax')(dense_3)
        #prediction = ExtractDim(axis=1, name='extract')(prediction_1)
        prediction = Flatten(name='flatten')(dense_3)
        prediction = SoftReRank(softmink=softmink, softmaxk=softmaxk, label=1, name='output')(prediction)
    elif sparsemil:
        dense_1 = Convolution2D(128,1,1,activation='relu',name='mil_1',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_1)
        dense_2 = Convolution2D(128,1,1,activation='relu',name='mil_2',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_1)
        prediction_1 = Convolution2D(1,1,1,activation='sigmoid',name='mil_3',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor),\
            activity_regularizer=activity_l1l2(l1=sparsemill1, l2=sparsemill2))(dense_2)
#        prediction_1 = Softmax4D(axis=1, name='softmax')(prediction_1)
        #dense_3 = Convolution2D(outdim,1,1,name='mil_3',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_2)
        #prediction_1 = Softmax4D(axis=1, name='softmax')(dense_3)
        #prediction_1 = ActivityRegularizerOneDim(l1=sparsemill1, l2=sparsemill2)(prediction_1)
        #prediction = MaxPooling2D((6,6), name='output')(prediction_1)
#        prediction_1 = Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, activation='sigmoid', border_mode='same', name='smooth', \
#            W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor), activity_regularizer=activity_l1l2(l1=sparsemill1, l2=sparsemill2))(prediction_1)
        prediction = Flatten(name='flatten')(prediction_1)
        if saveact:
          model = Model(input=inputs, output=prediction)
          return model
        prediction = RecalcExpand(axis=1, name='Recalcmil')(prediction)
    else:
        dense_1 = Flatten(name="flatten")(dense_1)
        dense_1 = Dense(4096, activation='relu',name='dense_1',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_1)
        dense_2 = Dropout(0.5)(dense_1)
        dense_2 = Dense(4096, activation='relu',name='dense_2',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_2)
        dense_3 = Dropout(0.5)(dense_2)
        dense_3 = Dense(outdim,name='dense_3',W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=l1factor, l2=l2factor))(dense_3)
        prediction = Activation("softmax",name="softmax")(dense_3)

    model = Model(input=inputs, output=prediction)

    if weights_path:
        model.load_weights(weights_path)

    return model
```

Comment: Can you include the full model definition (in python)?

Comment: Comment seems to have a limitation for the amount of code...

Comment: You have to edit your question and include the code in the question.

Comment: Oh thanks.I've re-edited it.

Comment: No, you have't. There is no code in your question as it currently stands.

Comment: sorry, it's ok now

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the format of your input shape does not match the currently configured channel ordering. Seems you are using the TensorFlow backend which defaults to using "channels last", while your input shape is in format "channels first".

Just change your input shape to (227, 227, 3) and your data accordingly.

Comment: THanks for your reply. But it is truely using Theano backend instead of Tensorflow.

Comment: @khj Then check file ~/.keras/keras.json for the image_dim_ordering parameter and report its value here.

Comment: {
    "epsilon": 1e-07, 
    "floatx": "float32", 
    "image_data_format": "channels_first", 
    "backend": "theano"
}

Do you mean this?